# parsing a drugbank.xml file

Tags: python, python-2.7, xml-parsing

Am trying out this code from Github.com on a drugbank xml file. I keep getting this error messsage:

```
usage: drugbank.py [-h] --input INPUT
drugbank.py: error: the following arguments are required: --input/-i
```

Being new to python, what could this mean?
Here is the long code:

```
def run(input):
    """Writes relational database text files for drugs, drug_target, drug_target_action, and targets tables.
    Input: the path of a DrugBank xml file.
    Output: text files that can be used as inputs to SQL tables.
    Method:
        1. Read and parse xml file.
        2. Extract data and save records as key, value pairs.
        3. Write output files."""
    #output file names
    drugs_out = input + '.drugs.txt'
    drug_target_out = input + '.drug_target.txt'
    drug_target_action_out = input + '.drug_target_action.txt'
    targets_out = input + '.targets.txt'

    #counter for number of records in each file
    record_counts = Counter()

    #open input file and parse xml
    #get drugbank namspace
    print('Reading and parsing xml file.')
    tree = etree.ElementTree(file=input)
    #a few namespace tricks to make the code more readable
    ns = tree.getroot().nsmap
    ns['db'] = ns[None]
    del ns[None]

    drugs = tree.xpath('db:drug', namespaces=ns)

    code........


def main():

    #command line arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='writes relational database text files for drugs, drug_target, drug_target_action, and targets',
        epilog='drugbankxml2db 1.0β1 ©2014 Michael Yourshaw all rights reserved',
    )
    parser.add_argument('--input', '-i', required=True,
                        help='drug bank xml file downloaded from http://www.drugbank.ca/system/downloads/current/drugbank.xml.zip',)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    run(input=args.input)

if __name__ == "__main__": sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback of your error message.

Comment: drugbank.py: error: argument --input/-i is required

Comment: looks like you need to give an argument. try `drugbank.py -i fileyoudownloaded.xml`

Comment: link to the Github repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script requires that you specify a value for the `--input` argument:

```
parser.add_argument('--input', '-i', required=True,
                    help='drug bank xml file downloaded from http://www.drugbank.ca/system/downloads/current/drugbank.xml.zip',)
```

`required=True` means you *have* to include `-i` or `--input` when running the script.

You are supposed to download the indicated URL yourself, unzip that file, then point the script to it with:

```
drugbank.py -i drugbank.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Am studying the code. Just wondering how am to point the script to the file. Pardon my demands.

Answer (score -2):

You can use **dbparser** R package of Drugs Bank database parser R package

```
install.packages("dbparser")
## load drugbank db
dbparser::read_drugbank_xml_db("drugbank.xml")
## load drugs data
drugs <- dbparser::parse_drug()
## load drug groups data
drug_groups <- dbparser::parse_drug_groups()
```

Complete reference and tutorial can be found here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbparser/index.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21716259)

Comment: @BartoszZasada: I did not notice your comment but now. I have update the answer. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Ali, when I am trying to run your code it is showing `'get_xml_db_rows' is not an exported object from 'namespace:dbparser'`. What is the meaning of this error

Comment: Hi @mostafiz67, the method is refactor to ```read_drugbank_xml_db``` in new versions.
Please review package documentation here
https://docs.ropensci.org/dbparser/reference/index.html

Comment: Hi @Ali, I will try and let you know!

Comment: Hi @mostafiz67, I hope you up vote my answer if you found it useful. Thanks

Comment: Hello @MohammedAli, yes, your answer was useful and I got help from you. Thank you.